# XNA game isn't exiting after calling Game.Exit()

Tags: c#, xna

I have this code:

```
public UnnamedGame()
{
    Exit();
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}
```

UnnamedGame is a derived class of Game (the base class for every XNA game). When I call Exit(); nothing happens, I set a breakpoint in the line after graphics and it reaches that line, which shouldn't happen.

I also did some testing, created a new XNA game and it works perfectly when I try to exit it without any extra code added that might change the functionality.

This is the code of the main program:

```
namespace UnnamedGame
{
#if WINDOWS || XBOX
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (UnnamedGame game = new UnnamedGame())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The game isn't running yet. You're ending the game in the constructor (which goes off in your `using` statement) but the game doesn't start until you call `game.Run()` inside the `using` statement.

Comment: Called it from inside Update() and Initialize() and it isn't working either. I did a while(true) { Exit(); } and again, no luck. I am using a networking library that uses a new thread, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad, found the problem.

I had to create the game window before closing it, that is why it wasn't working.